# Can i use nest {{}} in {{}} with jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

Yesterday I met a wrong when i wanted to use nest {{..}} in {{}},the variable `data` is a list.
 "data.append({'month': month, 'loan_type': data_type, 'channel': data_channel})". The `data_type` and `data_channel` are dictionary. In my '.tmpl' file I transmit two variables: `data` and `title_data`, the `title_data` is also a list, it represents the field name of the `data.data_type` and `data.data_channel`.
In my `.tmpl` file i want to ergodic the `title_data` to show the data.

```
{% for record in data %}
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="14">record.month</td>
            <td rowspan="7">loan_angel</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="7">loan_flow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>loan_angel</td>
            {% for title in title_data %}
            <td>{{ record.loan_type.loan_merchants_angel.{{ title }} }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr> 
{% endfor %}
```

But it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chenzhiping/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.2/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Users/chenzhiping/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.2/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/chenzhiping/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.2/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/chenzhiping/WoSai/bsm-report/report/loan/tasks.py", line 1064, in <module>
    stat_loan_funnel_model_data()
  File "/Users/chenzhiping/WoSai/bsm-report/report/loan/tasks.py", line 954, in stat_loan_funnel_model_data
    'finish_apply_merchants', 'approve_merchants', 'finish_sign_merchants'])
  File "/Users/chenzhiping/WoSai/bsm-report/report/notify.py", line 62, in gen_mail
    template = env.get_template(self.template)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 125, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 591, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/chenzhiping/WoSai/bsm-report/report/templates/loan_summary_v4.tmpl", line 37, in template
    <td>{{ record.loan_type.loan_merchants_angel.{{ title }} }}</td>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 497, in _parse
    return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 896, in parse
    result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 878, in subparse
    rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
    return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 198, in parse_for
    body = self.parse_statements(('name:endfor', 'name:else'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
    result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 878, in subparse
    rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
    return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 198, in parse_for
    body = self.parse_statements(('name:endfor', 'name:else'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
    result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 870, in subparse
    add_data(self.parse_tuple(with_condexpr=True))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 615, in parse_tuple
    args.append(parse())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 427, in parse_expression
    return self.parse_condexpr()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 432, in parse_condexpr
    expr1 = self.parse_or()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 445, in parse_or
    left = self.parse_and()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 454, in parse_and
    left = self.parse_not()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 465, in parse_not
    return self.parse_compare()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 469, in parse_compare
    expr = self.parse_math1()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 491, in parse_math1
    left = self.parse_concat()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 502, in parse_concat
    args = [self.parse_math2()]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 512, in parse_math2
    left = self.parse_pow()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 523, in parse_pow
    left = self.parse_unary()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 542, in parse_unary
    node = self.parse_postfix(node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 667, in parse_postfix
    node = self.parse_subscript(node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 700, in parse_subscript
    self.fail('expected name or number', attr_token.lineno)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 59, in fail
    raise exc(msg, lineno, self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected name or number
```

The `data` is

```
{'month': month,
 'loan_type': data_type, 
 'channel': data_channel}).
```

The `data_type` is

```
{'loan_merchants_angel': loan_merchants_angel, 
 'loan_merchants_flow': loan_merchants_flow}
```

Then the `loan_merchants_angel` is

```
{'total_loan_merchants': len(merchant_ids),
 'reach_loan_merchants': len(reach_loan_merchants),
 'try_apply_merchants': len(try_apply_merchants),
 'apply_merchants': len(apply_merchants),
 'finish_apply_merchants': len(finish_apply_merchants),
 'approve_merchants': len(approve_merchants),
 'finish_sign_merchants': len(finish_sign_merchants)}
```

Comment: can you paste the data you are passing ?

Comment: OK, I edit the question.

Comment: Try `record.loan_type.loan_merchants_angel[title]`.